# Genymotion Android VM stuck at "starting virtual device"

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

I'm having problems starting an Android VM (Nexus 5X) on Genymotion 3.0.0 trial on a Windows 10 host, and also on Virtualbox. I tried reinstalling Genymotion, but still doesn't work. The "Starting virtual machine" window pops up and just gets stuck there.

In Genymotion, I get the following error message before it just hangs there

```
init: Failed to reload policy
init: /recovery not specified in fstab

Waiting for eth0 link..
IP Management : 192.168.160.101
init: cannot find '/system/bin/vinput_seamless', disabling 'vinput_seamless'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/debuggerd64', disabling 'debuggerd64'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/install-recovery.sh', disabling 'install-recovery.sh'
```

I tried installing a few other Android devices in Genymotion (Nexus 6P/Pixel 3) but got the same problem starting them in Genymotion. I also couldn't start them in VirtualBox.

Anyone know what might be the problem?